# What thread are iphone delegate methods run in for webview and core location callbacks?

Tags: iphone, uiwebview, thread-safety, delegates, core-location

I have an issue that looks like a race condition with a webview callback and a location manager callback that interact with the same variables and an alert dialog - the dialog is created in the location callback and should be dismissed in the webview callback.  I thought that the delegate callbacks for standard objects like the webview and core location would be run in the main thread - is that not correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If in doubt then you can do something like this:

```
- (void) someCallback
{
    if ([NSThread isMainThread] ==  NO) {
        [self performSelectorOnMainThread: @selector(someCallback)];
    }
}
```

To make sure that you are always executing callback methods on the main thread and thus preventing concurrency issues.

You can also use a `@synchronized` block of course, but in my experience it is much better to rely on the synchronous nature of executing methods on the main thread.